# How do we get silverlight object container id

Tags: silverlight

how do we get html live division id in silver light, which hold the silver light object on page. 
for example : suppose i have two division, which hold the silver light object and each have different functionality. how do we identify on silver light button click, which is the current  container division in silver light.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need a call to a Javascript function (this post describes pretty well how to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav).

Then in JS it could be something like that:

```
var slApp1= parent.GetElementsByTagName('Div1')[0];
var slApp2= parent.GetElementsByTagName('Div2')[0];
```